# Why do checkbox property show as 'false' (not checked) when checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

My issue is that I have created a working CodePen that demonstrates my idea perfectly. When implementing the code on the web server it stops working correctly.

Specifically, my checkboxes should only allow one checkbox to be checked at a time. When the user attempts to check more than one, it unchecks the most recent, and gives an alert. It does this by checking for the "checked" property when the function is called. Depending on the property, a point is added or subtracted from the checkbox counter. Following, the checkbox counter is checked to ensure only one is selected - otherwise, it subtracts a point and unchecks the most reset checkbox.

When demonstrating on the web server, clicking each box subtracts from the checkbox counter. This in turn only allows for a constantly downward counting counter - no check really going on.

So my question:
Why does the checkbox seem to ignore the fact that it is checked?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <input id="thisone" class="chk" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
  <label for="thisone">Ha</label>
  <input id="thatone" class="chk" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
  <label for="thatone">Mwaha</label>
  <input id="thishere" class="chk" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
  <label for="thishere">Hi</label>
  <input id="thatthere" class="chk" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
  <label for="thatthere">Hello</label>  
</div>
<h3></h3>
```

**JS**

```
var DATA = {
  incomeChecks: 0  
};

function incomeCheck(e) {
  $('h3').text("income check, launched. DATA: "+DATA.incomeChecks);
  var targ = "#"+e.target.id;

  if( $(targ).prop( "checked" ) ) {
    DATA.incomeChecks += 1;
  }else{
    DATA.incomeChecks -= 1;
  }

  if( DATA.incomeChecks > 1 ) {
    $('h3').text($(targ).prop("checked"));
    $(targ).prop( "checked", false );
    DATA.incomeChecks -= 1;
    alert("Please select only one.");
  }
}

$('#container input').on( "click", incomeCheck );
```

CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/vulpcod3z/pen/RNwOez?editors=101).
Project [here](http://jointprogram.umd.edu/surv/). Go to the question that references income (page 12).

Comment: I haven't fully understood the problem yet, but this sounds like you want radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: They would work, but for specific task at hand, they need to be checkboxes, with radio functionality..

Comment: It would be easier to just deselect the rest when selecting one. Other than that the code that you showed us has no real problems, did you check your IDs on the server that they are right and unique?

Comment: So I guess I'm over-complicating things? If I were to deselect as a new one is selected, I'm assuming I would loop through all inputs with the checked property? I did check the ID's, all is good. HOWEVER, this is straying a bit. If you follow the second link I just posted you can see the issue. It's like the browser stops reading properties.

Comment: You are, in fact, reusing IDs in your project page. I see `quest-chkbox-2` used three times. That said, radio buttons are the right approach in this case.

Comment: @Blazemonger Is this because the 'quest-chkbox-X' id is being used elsewhere on other pages? I figured that when I specified that the event fires only when clicking on these inputs from page 12 that the event.target.id was linked to the input I was clicking.

Comment: Line 195-196: `var targ = "#"+e.target.id;  if( $(targ).prop( "checked" ) ) {` -- that's pointing to the wrong input. IDs must always be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var targ = "#"+e.target.id;
```

must be more specific like

```
var targ = "#page_12 #"+e.target.id;
```

This is because you are using the same IDs for each page.

Comment: The correct solution is not to be more specific, it's to use unique IDs.

Comment: Ok that fixes things. @Blazemonger as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your problem, but maybe this is because the server is treating the defaults on your check boxes differently. In your HTML, you have set the value properties for all the checkboxes to 1, but the value of a check box is not the same thing as the checked property of a checkbox. When you check these boxes you are changing the checked property from missing to true.

Perhaps you could see if adding checked="false" to the inputs:

```
<input id="thisone" class="chk" type="checkbox" checked="false" value="1"/>
```

But also like the others said, what you are really looking for is a radio button. Checkboxes are only for situations where you can have multiple things selected at the same time.

Comment: The only reason I did not do this is because when you use 'checked' like that, it is a attribute. Somewhere in the docs, it says that when checking the attribute 'checked' it doesn't change its value when checked or unchecked, whereas the property 'checked' changes as the box is clicked.